# Double quote string data showing in triple quote on google storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have one file in below format.

name dept_id
"cs" "101"
"Mech" "102"

When I am saving this file on google storage and then again trying to open the file then the contents looks like

name dept_id
"""cs""" """101"""
"""mech""" """102"""

I want the file field only in double quote not in triple quote.
Is there any way to resolve this problem.

Comment: The solution is to tell Google storage that the original double quotes in your input are not really part of the data, but rather are just there for escaping.  BTW, the triple double quotes probably just means two double quotes. to form a literal double quote, followed by a third double quote to escape.

Comment: how can i implement this.. do you have any example for this..if yes pls share..

Comment: What do you mean by "saving this file on Google Storage"?  Where is the data coming from?  How is it being saved?

Comment: @Kolban When I am saving file from my local file system or from big query table in above format I am always getting triple quote data from google storage bucket

Comment: Can you clarify with more example and detail?  For example, as of right now I'm assuming you have a  text file that contains your original details and then using gsutil to copy the file to GCS and then copying it back and the content has changed.  Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @kolban To save data from Bigquery I am using BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator operator and also I tried to load text file from my local system to google cloud bucket from UI but the output from bucket is coming only in triple quotes

Comment: How do you read your file? How do you save it to GCS?

Answer (score 0):

If the file format is CSV use 2 doubles quotes(one for escaping) instead of one double quote in your initial file. In CSV double quotes must be escaped with another double quote.
The initial data will be look like

```
name dept_id ""cs"" ""101"" ""Mech"" ""102""
```